# How to open a register form only in sunday

Tags: laravel

I'm using Laravel 5.7 and I want to open a specific page (register page) only in sundays How to do that ?

Comment: Delete the page every monday morning and re-create it every sunday morning

Comment: I want to d it automatically dude !

Comment: Make a copy of the file of the view with the form, and another without the form. Then create two crons: One cron executes one script that executes every sunday at 00:00 and copies the file with the form in the working file, and another cron executes one script that copies the file without the form every monday at 00:00

Comment: If you do like this, you could still `POST` your form. Unless you want to do the same work for the controller file, which is _slightly_ error prone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check today is Sunday, then you need to user PHP Carbon library(this library is default included in Laravel).

Here is an example how you will find the solution of your problem.

Like you have a controller name `RegistrationController`:-

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class RegistrationController extends Controller {

    public function register()
    {
        $dt = Carbon::now();

        if(!$dt->isSunday()) {
            // here you can add your code if today is not sunday.
            return redirect('home'); 
        }

        // put your code here to open registration form.
        return view('users.registration');
    }
}
```

If you want to deal with `Date` and `Time` then Carbon is a good library for this.

Here is the reference [click here](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/)

Comment: It workd but the user can play with the system date and open the register page , how can I restrict him ?

Comment: @Belhedi here, carbon will not work according to user system date. It will work with server dates. So it will not impact on database if user change system date.

Answer (score 0):

You can use blade to check if the weekday is sunday.

```
@if(today()->dayOfWeek == 0)
<form>
      ........
</form>
@else
<div>Please comeback on Sunday</div>
@endif
```

Comment: It always puzzled me that sunday is the first day of week in US

Comment: i suggest using controller to place all the logic that handles checking of sunday for security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

first call the carbon `use Carbon\Carbon;`
then in your controller do something like this

```
 $dt = Carbon::now();

    if($dt->dayOfWeek == Carbon::SUNDAY)

          {
           dd('sunday');
           return view('user.register');

          }
         else{

            dd('not sunday'); 
           //do not open registration form
    }
```

upvote if it helps. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Question already answered, but I think that a more elegant way would be to use a Middleware for that particular route (or routes) which check the day (as @Lakhwinder Singh suggested).

You can start writing this file into `app/Http/Middlewares/DisableOnSunday.php`

```
namespace App\Http\Middlewares;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class DisableOnSunday {
    public function handle($request, Closure $next) {
        if(!$dt->isSunday()) {
            // here you can add your code if today is not sunday.
            return redirect('home'); 
        }
        return next();
    }
}
```

This way you can, in future, add the same feature for another route, or group of routes, of whole controllers.